# Qual é a finalidade do while(*variavel) e if(!*variavel) nas declarações "while" e "if"?

Tags: c, ponteiro, if, característica-linguagem, while

No Code Review há uma [implementação de uma lista simplesmente encadeada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110165/simple-singly-linked-list-implementation-in-c) que eu estou utilizando.

Porem, na resposta de um dos usuários, ele fez algumas modificações na lista, e teve uma modificação em particular que me deixou com dúvidas.

A modificação que o usuário fez foi no procedimento `add()`:

```
void add(struct LinkedList *list, int value) {
    if(list->firstElement == NULL) {
        struct Element *newElement;
        newElement = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));

        newElement->value = value;
        newElement->nextElement = NULL;

        list->firstElement = newElement;
    } else {
        struct Element *lastElement;

        lastElement = list->firstElement;

        while(lastElement->nextElement != NULL) {
            lastElement = lastElement->nextElement;   
        }

        struct Element *newElement;
        newElement = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));

        newElement->value = value;
        newElement->nextElement = NULL;

        lastElement->nextElement = newElement;
    }
}
```

Para:

```
void add(List* head, int value) {
    while(*head)
        head = &head[0]->next;
    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
    if(!*head) abort();
    **head = (Node){0, value};
}
```

E minha dúvida esta na declaração `while` e `if`, que estão declaradas da seguinte forma como mostra abaixo:

```
while(*head)
```

e:

```
if(!*head)
```

É a primeira vez que eu vejo uma declaração do `while` e `if` como esta acima, utilizando ponteiro.

---

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber o que essas declarações `while(*head)` e `if(!*head)` significam e qual é a finalidade de uma declaração deste tipo com ponteiro em comandos de controle do fluxo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No código em questão, `List` está definido como

```
typedef node* List;
```

Logo, `head` é na verdade ponteiro de ponteiro para um nó, e `*head`, por consequência, guarda um ponteiro para nó. A parte do `while` poderia ser escrita explicitamente como

```
while (*head != NULL)
    head = &((*head)->next)
```

Ou seja, anda-se na lista até chegar ao fim dela (indicado por NULL). Analogamente, a parte do `if` pode ser escrita como

```
if (*head == NULL) abort();
```

Como vem logo após o malloc, está verificando se o mesmo devolveu NULL (essa verificação não era feita no código original).

Sobre a finalidade, acredito que a vantagem da implementação no código em questão, por meio de ponteiros de ponteiro, visa a evitar escrever duas versões de add() (uma com lista vazia e outra caso contrário), bem como não é necessário mandar o último elemento apontar para o novo após inseri-lo.